# Data type isnt well received by the database

Tags: php, sql, oracle

So the big idea is I want to insert to the Oracle database value through input tag with number type. The problem is when I Input value that is > 0, it works fine. but when I left if unfilled, this error appears,

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00936: missing expression in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Content\Fabrication\Update\FabricationQC\processExceededQcQty.php
>   on line 76

So here is the input tag:

```
echo "<td><input name='dataMarkingQc' id='dataMarkingQc' type='number' min='0' max='$availableMarkingQc' width='5' value='0'></td>";
```

And the processing method is like this,

```
$dataMarkingQc = intval($_POST['dataMarkingQc']);

if ($dataMarkingQc   == 0){ $markingQcUser = "";   $markingQcDate = '';   } 
            else { $markingQcUser = $username; $markingQcDate =   'SYSDATE';}

$updateQcHistSql = "INSERT INTO FABRICATION_QC_HIST (MARKING_QC, MARKING_QC_DATE, MARKING_QC_SIGN) VALUES ($dataMarkingQc, $markingQcDate, '$markingQcUser')";
```

And the `var_dump` is this

```
["dataMarkingQc"]=> string(1) "0"
```

So the problem is, when I submit 0 value in the input tag, the error appears. Data type for `MARKING_QC` is int.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code. Reformatted here for readability. Clean formatting for readability always makes it easier to debug stuff like this:

```
$dataMarkingQc = intval($_POST['dataMarkingQc']);

if ($dataMarkingQc == 0) {
  $markingQcUser = "";
  $markingQcDate = '';
} 
else {
  $markingQcUser = $username;
  $markingQcDate = 'SYSDATE';
}

$updateQcHistSql = "INSERT INTO FABRICATION_QC_HIST (MARKING_QC, MARKING_QC_DATE, MARKING_QC_SIGN)"
                 . " VALUES ($dataMarkingQc, $markingQcDate, '$markingQcUser')"
                 ;
```

Maybe this would work better:

```
$dataMarkingQc = intval($_POST['dataMarkingQc']);

$markingQcUser = $dataMarkingQc == 0 ? null : $username;
$markingQcDate = $dataMarkingQc == 0 ? null : 'SYSDATE';

$updateQcHistSql = "INSERT INTO FABRICATION_QC_HIST (MARKING_QC, MARKING_QC_DATE, MARKING_QC_SIGN) VALUES ('$dataMarkingQc', '$markingQcDate', '$markingQcUser')";
```

I believe the issue was the lack of single quotes `'` around `$dataMarkingQc` and `$markingQcDate`. I also simplified the logic for setting `$markingQcUser` & `$markingQcDate` by using ternary logic and actually setting a `null` value instead of just an empty string.

Comment: if I put '' quotes around $dataMarkingQc and $markingQcDate it throws an error. plus your if condition doesn't work

Comment: if I follow your code and then I put some numeric value, it throws this `Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected` and if I leave them to 0 it still throws the previous error